# Java- Cannot find symbol (swing)

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, symbols

I have a Simon game that I'm working on, and I've been debugging for a while before moving on to finish. Just this one error left so far; Compiler (NetBeans IDE rather) reporting error; specifically "Cannot find symbol MenuPanel ; Class: BorderPanel". I know it is not within this class, but I'm not entirely sure how where to point it to. Relevant code below:

```
package simon;

import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Color.*;


/**
 *  Main Class
 * @author Chris Mailloux
 */
public class Simon
{
    // Variable declarations.
    public static final String[] colors = {"Green", "Red", "Yellow", "Blue"};
    public static ArrayList<String> pattern = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static int currentScore = 0;
    public static int iterator = 0;
    public static boolean isPlayerTurn = false;
    // PLACEHOLDER FOR HIGHSCORE RETRIEVAL FROM FILE
    public static int highScore = 0; // TEMPORARY

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        GameWindow window = new GameWindow();
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

/**
 * Class for main game window.
 * @author Chris
 */
class GameWindow extends JFrame
{
    GameWindow()
    {
        // Set basic properties of frame.
        setSize(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
        setTitle("Simon");
        setResizable(true);
        setLocation(DEFAULT_HORIZONTAL_LOCATION, DEFAULT_VERTICAL_LOCATION);
        // PLACEHOLDER FOR IMAGE ICON

        // Adding Menu Panel
        MenuPanel menuPanel = new MenuPanel();
        add(menuPanel);

        // Adding buttons panel.
        ButtonsPanel buttonsPanel = new ButtonsPanel();
        add(buttonsPanel);

        // Adding Border layout helper panel.
        BorderPanel borderPanel = new BorderPanel();
        add(borderPanel);

        // Setting grid layout (with spaces)
        buttonsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2, 20, 20)); 

        // Setting background color of main panel to black.
        buttonsPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
    }
    // Declaring window positioning constants.
    public static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 800;
    public static final int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 800;

    // TEMPORARY PLACEHOLDER FOR SCREENSIZE CALCULATIONS
    public static final int DEFAULT_HORIZONTAL_LOCATION = 0;
    public static final int DEFAULT_VERTICAL_LOCATION = 0;
}

/**
 * Class to hold the buttonsPanel
 * @author Chris
 */
class ButtonsPanel extends JPanel
{
    public static JButton greenButton = new JButton();
    public static JButton redButton = new JButton();
    public static JButton yellowButton = new JButton();
    public static JButton blueButton = new JButton();

    ButtonsPanel()
    {
       // Setting background color of buttons.
       greenButton.setBackground(Color.GREEN);  // NEED COLOR CONSTANTS
       redButton.setBackground(Color.RED);  
       yellowButton.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);    
       blueButton.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

       // Add buttons to panel. (In order)
        add(greenButton);
            add(redButton);
        add(yellowButton);
            add(blueButton);

       // Creating ActionListeners for 4 main buttons.
        ActionListener greenAction = new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                greenClicked();
            }
        };

        ActionListener redAction = new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                redClicked();
            }
        };

        ActionListener yellowAction = new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                yellowClicked();
            }
        };

        ActionListener blueAction = new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                blueClicked();
            }
        };

            // Associate actions with buttons.
        greenButton.addActionListener(greenAction);
        redButton.addActionListener(redAction);
        yellowButton.addActionListener(yellowAction);
        blueButton.addActionListener(blueAction);
    }

        // Handling button activations.
        public static void greenClicked()
        {
            // TODO
        }

        public static void redClicked()
        {
            // TODO
        }

        public static void yellowClicked()
        {
            // TODO
        }

        public static void blueClicked()
        {
            // TODO
        }
}
/**
 * Menu buttons panel.
 * @author Chris Mailloux
 */
class MenuPanel extends JPanel
{
    public MenuPanel()
    {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        // Menu panel buttons.
        JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
        JButton scoreDisplay = new JButton(String.valueOf(Simon.currentScore));
        JButton highScoreDisplay = new JButton(String.valueOf(Simon.highScore));
        add(startButton);
        add(scoreDisplay);
        add(highScoreDisplay);
        scoreDisplay.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        highScoreDisplay.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        startButton.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        scoreDisplay.setEnabled(false);
        scoreDisplay.setEnabled(false);
        // ActionListeners for menu buttons.
        ActionListener startButtonAction = new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                Game.startGame();
            }
        };
        startButton.addActionListener(startButtonAction);
    }
 }

/**
 * Border Panel support class.
 * @author Chris Mailloux
 */
class BorderPanel extends JPanel
{
    BorderPanel()
    {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(menuPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
}
/**
* Main game logic class.
* @author Chris
*/
class Game extends Simon // Extends to allow to inherit variables.
{
// Resets variables for new game.
public static void startGame()
{
    isPlayerTurn = false;
    pattern.clear();
    currentScore = 0;
    iterator = 0;
    gamePlay(); // Starts game
}

public static void gamePlay()
{
    if (isPlayerTurn = false)
    {
        computerTurn();
    }
    else
    {
        playerTurn();
    }
}

public static void computerTurn()
{
    ButtonsPanel.greenButton.setEnabled(false);
    ButtonsPanel.redButton.setEnabled(false);
    ButtonsPanel.yellowButton.setEnabled(false);
    ButtonsPanel.blueButton.setEnabled(false);
    iterator = 0; // So CPU can use iterator to show pattern.
    int randInt = (int) Math.random() * 4;
    String randColor = colors[randInt];
    pattern.add(new String(randColor));
    showPattern();
}

public static void playerTurn()
{
    iterator = 0;
    ButtonsPanel.greenButton.setEnabled(true);
    ButtonsPanel.redButton.setEnabled(true);
    ButtonsPanel.yellowButton.setEnabled(true);
    ButtonsPanel.blueButton.setEnabled(true);
}

/**
 * Handles scoring and checks inputs for correctness.
 * @author Chris Mailloux
 */
public static void check()
{
    if(lastInput == pattern.get(iterator))
    {
        iterator++;
        if(iterator > currentScore)
        {
            currentScore++;
            if(currentScore > highScore)
            {
                highScore++;
                // PLACEHOLDER TO WRITE HIGHSCORE TO FILE.
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        gameOver();
    }
}

public static void showPattern()
{
    int j = 0;
    while (j < pattern.size())
    {
        String showerHelper = pattern.get(j); // Helper variable.
        switch (showerHelper)
        {
            case "Green" : ButtonsPanel.greenClicked();
            case "Red" : ButtonsPanel.redClicked();
            case "Yellow" : ButtonsPanel.yellowClicked();
            case "Blue" : ButtonsPanel.blueClicked();
            break; // Fallthrough handler.
            default: System.out.println("Error: Invalid value for pattern"
                    + " ArrayList, or improper storage of variable in the"
                    + " showerHelper variable.");
        }
        j++;
    }
}

    public static void gameOver()
    {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Comment: Other than a lot of missing imports and at least one missing...something (`menuPanel` in `BorderPanel`).

Comment: My imports are at the top. I'll post the rest of the code. One sec...

Answer (score 2):

In your class `BorderPanel` you're using a variable `menuPanel` that ... doesn't exist.

```
add(menuPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

That's why it's telling you that it's a missing symbol.

Perhaps you meant to create a new instance of `MenuPanel`?

```
add(new MenuPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Comment: Should be where? It's not, and the error you're receiving is exactly what that would cause.

Comment: This code in the gameWindow Constructor should be creating that variable though, should it not?
            MenuPanel menuPanel = new MenuPanel();
            add(menuPanel);

Comment: that has absolutely nothing to do with your `BorderPanel` class.

Comment: @RomanVottner And technically that's perfectly legal (You just wouldn't do it in a real project); only one class is defined `public`; that has nothing to do with the error he's receiving which I've ... explained in my answer.

Comment: Yes, as @BrianRoach has described, the symbol `menuPanel` (with a lower case `m`) is not defined in the scope in which it is used.

Comment: Okay, Brian, you were right about creating a new instance. It fixed the problem, but I'm not sure why. Could you explain? Sorry if I seem a little dense, I'm just new to this and want to have a concrete understanding of what's going on. In my other panels, I was able to add them to the frame without using the new keyword. Am I just missing something obvious here?(Quite possible, Really tired right now.)

Comment: @user3202949 variables have *scope*. Anything outside of that class doesn't exist. Just because you've put numerous classes in one file doesn't affect that.

Comment: @BrianRoach I didn't say anything other :) Was just a foolish comment, sorry therefore. Just to add something more valueable: `if(lastInput == pattern.get(iterator))` in `public static void check()` almost at the bottom of the code - the `lastInput` is also not defined (only occurence)

Comment: @user3202949 The new operator creates a new instance (=object) of a class. Usually the block (area between `{` and `}`) defines the scope of a variable - this means other objects or methods are able to "see" the object. Once the block has ended, its name is unknown to other classes/methods/... defining an object at class-level makes a variable accessible to all methods of the class (I assume no static methods here for simplicity), an object declared in a method is only visible within that method - if it has the same name as the variable at class-level - it shadows the class-level variable

Comment: @user3202949 which means that the class-level (outer) variable is not accessible and instead the inner (local) variable is taken.

Comment: I am aware lastInput is not defined, I haven't gotten to it yet,but thanks for being patient and looking it over. I don't understand it entirely but I'm definitely understanding it more than I did. So in theory, If I needed to access something in one class from another class, how would I go about it? Would a simple accessor method work? Which class would it go in (former or latter). And why wouldn't declaring the thing in question public make it visible. (I understand the shadowing concept you explained, but I'm trying to think of this on a general level) Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: @user3202949 Passing values/objects from one object to an other happens via arguments passed to constructor/method-calls or public field invocations. F.e. your `lastInput` variable could be provided by the caller of the check-method, therefore the method need to be modified to `public static void check(String lastInput) {...}`. Probably somewhere in your `blueClicked()` method you can now send the input when obviously blue was clicked via `Game.check("Blue");` to the Game. If the method would not have been static you would need to invoke the method on an instance of the game instead.

Answer (score 0):

If your posted code is complete, then you most likely need an import statement for the missing class.

```
import <path-to-borderpanel>.BorderPanel;
```

It looks like from your code that `BorderPanel` (along with the others) may be in the default package (i.e. - no `package` statement at the top of the file in which they are defined).  In that case, you will need to put them in a package in order for them to be accessible to other, non-default packages.  If you place them in the `simon` package, then you won't need to import them at all.

Comment: I shouldn't need to import a class that is created within the program. Oh wait damnit sorry, forgot the bottom half of the code. one sec haha god it's late.

Comment: Sorry bout that, code is now all there, my copypasta skills need work.

Comment: @user3202949 So is this all one big file?

Comment: Yes. It's a smaller program so I saw no need to split into different files.